# PYAML throwing a representation error

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, representation, pyyaml

I have this nested dictionary class, whose instances I need to dump into YAML

```
class NestedDict(dict):
    """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value
```

On dumping this dictionary:

```
pyaml.dump(nesteddict)
```

I get this error(only an excerpt of the entire message object posted):

> "RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: {'a1401': 'ts755',
>   'ts64': {'topic': {'a1561': 'Process Control'}}, 'a1450': 'ts107',
>   'a1609': 'ts341', 'a1400': 'ts753', ......

So how to neatly represent this in YAML? I read that PyYAML does  support nested recursive structures.

Comment: Can you paste the code of objects that you are trying to create(basically the input and output). Try using the dumper.

Answer (score 2):

YAML does support nested recursive structures:

```
import ruamel.yaml

data = [1, 3]
data.append(data)

print ruamel.yaml.dump(data)
```

Will give you YAML with an anchor (`&id001`) and a reference (`*id001`):

```
&id001
- 1
- 3
- *id001
```

And your simple derivative of a `dict` can be dumped, at least with [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) without a problem as well¹:

```
import ruamel.yaml

class NestedDict(dict):
    """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value

data = NestedDict(a=1, b=2)
data['c'] = data

print ruamel.yaml.dump(data)
```

This gives you:

```
&id001 !!python/object/new:__main__.NestedDict
dictitems:
  a: 1
  b: 2
  c: *id001
```

If you need a more complex representation, e.g. filter out some
dict values, you have to tell ruamel.yaml how to represent your objects. 
To tell it that NestedDict has a representer you can either make it a subclass of `ruamel.yaml.YAMLObject`, provide a class attribute `yaml_tag = "!NestedDict"` and implement `__repr__()`; or you can provide an explicit representer.

The latter is what is internally used and IMO somewhat easier to implement as you can just piggy-back on the dictionary code by having that return a dictionary representation (i.e top level key-value pairs) of your object.

```
def nested_dict_representer(dumper, node):
    return dumper.represent_mapping("!NestedDict", xyz)
```

Where `xyz` is some key-value pair representation of your object.

---

¹ <sub>Disclaimer: I am the author of that package, which is an enhanced version of PyYAML.</sub>